# React Native: How to put a long terms and services condition in React Native?

Tags: react-native, text

[I use this to add long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XWrL.png):
[image: Adding long text]

[If too long it will grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZYru.png):
[image: When too long it is grayed out]

Once it got too long, it is grayed out. So I have to add another POLITICAL2,....
And then POLITICALTEXT = POLITICAL1 + POLITICAL2+....

Doesn't React-native handle long text?

Is there any other way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: @slashsharp But I need to put a very long text here. It'll grey out if it's too long